# Vector on matched paired id in different rows

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I would like to create a vector that identifies the rows that have a matched identifier. For instance, `hldid` is the household identifier, `persid` the personal identifier and `partner id` the matched identifier.

What I would like is to create a vector `couple` when `persid` has a `partner`.

```
       hldid persid partner_id age sex child
1     243312      2         91  20   2     0
2     243312     91          2  29   1     0
3     103340      0          0   6   1     2
4     103340      2         91  39   2     2
5     103340      4          0  14   2     2
6     103340     91          2  42   1     2
7    1105347      2          0  25   2     2
8    1105347      3          3  50   2     2
9    1105347     91          0  25   1     2
10 110322323      3          0  15   2     1
11 110322323     10          0  15   2     1
```

This would give

```
       hldid persid partner_id age sex child couple
1     243312      2         91  20   2     0      1
2     243312     91          2  29   1     0      1
3     103340      0          0   6   1     2      0
4     103340      2         91  39   2     2      1
5     103340      4          0  14   2     2      0
6     103340     91          2  42   1     2      1
7    1105347      2          0  25   2     2      0 
8    1105347      3          3  50   2     2      0
9    1105347     91          0  25   1     2      0
10 110322323      3          0  15   2     1      0
11 110322323     10          0  15   2     1      0
```

I created a `loop` such as

```
df$couple = 0

 for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(
      df$hldid[i] == df$hldid[i+1] &
    (df$persid[i] == df$partner_id[i+1])
    )
    {
      df$couple[i] = 1
      df$couple[i+1] = 1
    }
  }
}
```

However, it is not working properly when identifiers are not next to each other.

```
df = structure(list(hldid = c(243312L, 243312L, 103340L, 103340L, 
103340L, 103340L, 1105347L, 1105347L, 1105347L, 110322323L, 110322323L
), persid = c(2L, 91L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 91L, 2L, 3L, 91L, 3L, 10L), 
partner_id = c(91, 2, 0, 91, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), age = c(20L, 
29L, 6L, 39L, 14L, 42L, 25L, 50L, 25L, 15L, 15L), sex = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), child = c(0, 0, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10280b2e0>)
```

Comment: Can you describe in words the logic for the `couple` column? Based on the result you show, it seems like "if row has a `partner_id` that is not 0 and not the same as the persid (e.g., row 8), then `couple` is 1, otherwise `couple` is 0". I would code this as `df$couple = with(df, ifelse(partner_id != 0 & partner_id != persid, 1, 0))`. Is that correct? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Conversely, your code attempt seems to only care about the row order, but you say that it doesn't work when the identifiers are not next to each other. For your desired result, does it matter if they identifiers are next to each other or not? I can't tell...

Comment: I need that rows in the same `hldid` who have both a `persid` and a `partner_id` to be identified with a `1`.

Comment: yes actually this simple solution seems to work `df$couple = with(df, ifelse(partner_id != 0 & partner_id != persid, 1, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't thought about the logic for exactly what the `couple` means. Looking at your desired result, it looks to me like any row with a `partner_id` that is not 0 and not equal to `persid` gets a 1, all other rows get 0. This is a simple condition and is simple to implement:

```
df$couple = with(df, ifelse(partner_id != 0 & partner_id != persid, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Yes I did not see this simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Gregor's comments, I'm not entirely sure I follow the logic of partners needing to be in consecutive rows. To me, it seems to me like this could be solved with a join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
merge(df, df, by = )

df[df,
   .(i.hldid, i.persid, i.partner_id, i.age, i.sex, i.child,
     couple = ifelse(is.na(child) | i.partner_id == 0 | i.partner_id == i.persid, 0, 1)),
   on = c("hldid", "persid==partner_id")]

      i.hldid i.persid i.partner_id i.age i.sex i.child couple
 1:    243312        2           91    20     2       0      1
 2:    243312       91            2    29     1       0      1
 3:    103340        0            0     6     1       2      0
 4:    103340        2           91    39     2       2      1
 5:    103340        4            0    14     2       2      0
 6:    103340       91            2    42     1       2      1
 7:   1105347        2            0    25     2       2      0
 8:   1105347        3            3    50     2       2      0
 9:   1105347       91            0    25     1       2      0
10: 110322323        3            0    15     2       1      0
11: 110322323       10            0    15     2       1      0
```

Comment: In OP's example of desired result, row 8 is not flagged as a couple. Nor is any row where `partner_id` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

With plain base R,

```
tmp  <- df1[,c("persid", "partner_id")]
tmp2 <- t(apply(tmp, 1, sort))
tmp2 <- unique( tmp2[duplicated(tmp2),] )

df1$couple <-
as.integer(apply( tmp, 1, function(x) { all(x %in% tmp2)}))
```

---

```
#       hldid persid partner_id age sex child couple
#1     243312      2         91  20   2     0      1
#2     243312     91          2  29   1     0      1
#3     103340      0          0   6   1     2      0
#4     103340      2         91  39   2     2      1
#5     103340      4          0  14   2     2      0
#6     103340     91          2  42   1     2      1
#7    1105347      2          0  25   2     2      0
#8    1105347      3          3  50   2     2      0
#9    1105347     91          0  25   1     2      0
#10 110322323      3          0  15   2     1      0
#11 110322323     10          0  15   2     1      0
```